# SqlTransaction has completed, it is no longer usable, rollback issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, try-catch, sqlexception

I have been facing this error message once in a while:

> The SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

I am not sure what caused this error to pop up, I have tried setting SQL Timeout to infinity.

Is it because of my code structure?

This doesn't happen when small group of user, but happens frequently when huge group of user.

```vb
Public Function PostCustomerSet(ByVal ds As CustomerHeaderDetailDataSet, ByVal Table As String, ByRef SessionKeys As String, ByRef errMsg As String, ByVal SubmitType As Integer, ByVal callWrapper As Boolean) As String
    errMsg = Nothing
    Dim newkey As PrimaryKey
    Dim oldkey As PrimaryKey
    Try
        transaction = EnterpriseUtils.StartTransaction(Connection1, m_Dict)
        If ds.CustomerHeader.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim SessionKey As PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey.FromString(SessionKeys)
            Dim CustomerHeaderKey As PrimaryKey = EnterpriseUtils.VerifyDataRowKeys(ds.CustomerHeader.Rows(0), SessionKey, SubmitType)
            Dim OldCustomerHeaderKey As PrimaryKey = New PrimaryKey(CustomerHeaderKey)
            newkey = CustomerHeaderKey
            oldkey = OldCustomerHeaderKey
            
            If CustomerHeaderKey Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                If ds.CustomerHeader.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'check if record was not deleted during update
                    CustomerHeaderKey.Update(ds.CustomerHeader(0))
                    If SubmitType = 1 Then
                        EnterpriseUtils.UpdateTemporaryLinks("CustomerNumber", CustomerHeaderKey, OldCustomerHeaderKey, "CustomerDetail", transaction)
                        EnterpriseUtils.UpdateTemporaryLinks("CustomerNumber", CustomerHeaderKey, OldCustomerHeaderKey, "CustomerMultiPayments", transaction)
                    End If

                    
                    If callWrapper AndAlso ds.CustomerHeader(0).CustomerNumber.ToUpper <> "DEFAULT" Then
                        Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("enterprise.Customer_Control", Connection1)
                        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        Command.Transaction = transaction
                        Dim parameter As SqlParameter
                        '@CompanyID
                        parameter = New SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                        parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).CompanyID
                        Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                        'DivisionID
                        parameter = New SqlParameter("@DivisionID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                        parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).DivisionID
                        Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                        '@DepartmentID
                        parameter = New SqlParameter("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                        parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).DepartmentID
                        Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                        '@DocumentNumber
                        parameter = New SqlParameter("@DocumentNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                        parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).CustomerNumber
                        Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                End If
                transaction.Commit()
                transaction = Nothing
                Return CustomerHeaderKey.ToString()
            End If
        ElseIf ds.CustomerDetail.Count > 0 Then
            CustomerDetail_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerDetail)
            transaction.Commit()
            transaction = Nothing
        ElseIf ds.CustomerMiscCharges.Count > 0 Then
            CustomerMiscCharges_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerMiscCharges)
            transaction.Commit()
            transaction = Nothing
        ElseIf ds.CustomerMultiPayments.Count > 0 Then
            CustomerMultiPayment_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerMultiPayments)
            transaction.Commit()
            transaction = Nothing
        End If
        Return Nothing       
    Catch e As SqlException
        errMsg = "Please contact your system administrator. (code number: " + e.Number + ")" 'Message + ")"
        WebUtils.ProcessError(e, errMsg, EDIErrorType.SendEmailNotification Or EDIErrorType.WriteLog)
        Return Nothing
    Catch e As Exception
        errMsg = e.Message
        WebUtils.ProcessError(e, errMsg, EDIErrorType.SendEmailNotification Or EDIErrorType.WriteLog)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        If Not transaction Is Nothing Then
            transaction.Rollback()
        End If
        If Connection1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Connection1.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting
 `transaction = Nothing` after

```
transaction.Commit()
```

Which is causing this issue, you need to set this as nothing after Finally Method.

```
Public Function PostCustomerSet(ByVal ds As CustomerHeaderDetailDataSet, ByVal Table As String, ByRef SessionKeys As String, ByRef errMsg As String, ByVal SubmitType As Integer, ByVal callWrapper As Boolean) As String
errMsg = Nothing
Dim newkey As PrimaryKey
Dim oldkey As PrimaryKey
Try
    transaction = EnterpriseUtils.StartTransaction(Connection1, m_Dict)
    If ds.CustomerHeader.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim SessionKey As PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey.FromString(SessionKeys)
        Dim CustomerHeaderKey As PrimaryKey = EnterpriseUtils.VerifyDataRowKeys(ds.CustomerHeader.Rows(0), SessionKey, SubmitType)
        Dim OldCustomerHeaderKey As PrimaryKey = New PrimaryKey(CustomerHeaderKey)
        newkey = CustomerHeaderKey
        oldkey = OldCustomerHeaderKey

        If CustomerHeaderKey Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            If ds.CustomerHeader.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'check if record was not deleted during update
                CustomerHeaderKey.Update(ds.CustomerHeader(0))
                If SubmitType = 1 Then
                    EnterpriseUtils.UpdateTemporaryLinks("CustomerNumber", CustomerHeaderKey, OldCustomerHeaderKey, "CustomerDetail", transaction)
                    EnterpriseUtils.UpdateTemporaryLinks("CustomerNumber", CustomerHeaderKey, OldCustomerHeaderKey, "CustomerMultiPayments", transaction)
                End If


                If callWrapper AndAlso ds.CustomerHeader(0).CustomerNumber.ToUpper <> "DEFAULT" Then
                    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("enterprise.Customer_Control", Connection1)
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    Command.Transaction = transaction
                    Dim parameter As SqlParameter
                    '@CompanyID
                    parameter = New SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                    parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).CompanyID
                    Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                    'DivisionID
                    parameter = New SqlParameter("@DivisionID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                    parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).DivisionID
                    Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                    '@DepartmentID
                    parameter = New SqlParameter("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                    parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).DepartmentID
                    Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                    '@DocumentNumber
                    parameter = New SqlParameter("@DocumentNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 36)
                    parameter.Value = ds.CustomerHeader(0).CustomerNumber
                    Command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            End If
            transaction.Commit()
            transaction = Nothing
            Return CustomerHeaderKey.ToString()
        End If
    ElseIf ds.CustomerDetail.Count > 0 Then
        CustomerDetail_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerDetail)
        transaction.Commit()

    ElseIf ds.CustomerMiscCharges.Count > 0 Then
        CustomerMiscCharges_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerMiscCharges)
        transaction.Commit()

    ElseIf ds.CustomerMultiPayments.Count > 0 Then
        CustomerMultiPayment_Adapter.Update(ds.CustomerMultiPayments)
        transaction.Commit()

    End If
    Return Nothing       
Catch e As SqlException
    errMsg = "Please contact your system administrator. (code number: " + e.Number + ")" 'Message + ")"
    WebUtils.ProcessError(e, errMsg, EDIErrorType.SendEmailNotification Or EDIErrorType.WriteLog)
    Return Nothing
Catch e As Exception
    errMsg = e.Message
    WebUtils.ProcessError(e, errMsg, EDIErrorType.SendEmailNotification Or EDIErrorType.WriteLog)
    Return Nothing
Finally
    If Not transaction Is Nothing Then
        transaction.Rollback()
    End If
    If Connection1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Connection1.Close()
    End If
End Try
transaction = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for your feedback! I will try it and let you know

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I have a question that would like ask for your opinion.
My stored procedure in SQL has already implemented rollback, something like this at the end of the stored procedure:
WriteError:
IF @@TRANCOUNT < 2
 ROLLBACK TRAN T1
ELSE
 COMMIT TRAN T1                                                                                             Do i still need this transaction.rollback in VB.net?                                         Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Nope, in that you should be good,  you won't need to call BeginTrans or Rollback Trans in your code.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh! Appreciate it alot for your prompt reply.

Comment: Sure, please mark this reply as "Answer was helpful", if given solutions helped. thanks.

Comment: Hi Sir, i have 1 more question to ask before I go,  If i remove the rollback in the SQL, would it be a better solution? As if i remain the rollback in VB.NET, it can also helps me rollback some VB.NET processing error.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use rollback and commit in VB.NET if we are executing query from code itself.. If you are using SQL Stored Procedure, it will be good ( and make sense) to maintain rollback functionality in Stored Procedure only.

Comment: @RakeshYadav Can you provide any documentation or reasoning that explains why setting transaction to `null` outside of the `try/catch/finally` fixes the problem? It doesn't look like that would functionally make a difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Matt:  I don't have docs at this point, will check if i can find something. but you are doing this because you are using rollback transaction approach as well.